# Failed to export application Command-line Error 132

Tags: android

When I try to export my Android application in eclipse I just get this error.
Failed to export application Command-line Error 132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be bug in the build-tools version 18.

See here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60448

Try it with 17 or 19 version.